# Unable to use Domain of Email Address, and Still Authenticate System Users

Tags: email, dovecot

I have a working config for Dovecot and Postfix that gives me a working email server for a certain domain, for users who are part of the `mail` group.

Now, I want to receive mail for a new domain on that server, and store mail for `user@domain-a.com` at `/home/user/Mail/domain-a.com/*`, and `user@domain-b.com` at `/home/user/Mail/domain-b.com/*`.  The problem is, to authenticate with the poorly-documented `passwd` Dovecot module, you have to strip off the domain name, and leave just the user name, so that the domain name is no longer available for use in `maildir:~/Mail/%d`.

I've tried using `passwd-file` instead, but that just broke everything, and isn't how I want to do it anyway.

Do I have to fork Dovecot to add a `username` option to the `args` for the `passwd` `userdb` driver?